# Why is the ext4 file system so sensitive to crashes?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ntfs

I've been using Linux on ext4 file systems for many years - before that I used Windows on NTFS for many years. The ext4 file system strikes me as much more sensitive to crashes than NTFS. If I had a crash on Windows, the NTFS file system was always able to restore operation almost without problems, whereas the ext4 file system - well, you always hear that you must "never, never, ever!" just pull the plug on an ext4 file system, or it WILL be damaged! And of course, I've experienced that myself a number of times - sometimes, an ext4 system WILL lose power due to unforeseen events.

Why has a more crash-resilient filesystem not been adopted by various Linux distributions?

Comment: You just cannot ask this question seriously without precisely specifying what options are selected at mkfs time AND, even more important : mount options. And, BTW, all distributions I know offer support for zfs.

Comment: **well, you always hear that you must "never, never, ever!" just pull the plug on an ext4 file system, or it WILL be damaged** `[citation needed]`, as wikipedia would say. Ext4 is a journaling file system, it's pretty hard to damage it with power outages, that's *exactly* what it's designed to be safe against. Can you tell us what the consequences of our crashes were in terms of actually damaged file system? Because otherwise, I just dispute your claim as unfounded and contrary to both design of and experience with ext4.

Comment: There is more than just `ext4` for Linux. Ive never had a problem with `xfs` after a crash.

Comment: In my experience NTFS is indeed more resilient to outages than ext4. Linux has many other filesystems, please try them, maybe they'll suit you better.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov We always have diametrically different experiences with file systems :) I've not once managed to damage an ext4 with a power outage (aside from you know, that power outage actually damaging the physical hard drive), which is perfectly logical, because, again, you *cannot* find a time at which a power outage would damage the file system structure. That's really literally the point of a journaling file system!

Comment: re: "Never, ever pull the plug on ext4" - it's not hard to find the exact same advice for FAT and NTFS and pretty much every other filesystem.  That's because doing so will, at the very least, lose the data written but not yet flushed to disk OR, at the worst, actually corrupt the filesystem.  Corruption is far less likely with ext4 and NTFS (nearly impossible) than it is with FAT (almost certain to happen).  It's one of the reasons why Windows mounts removable FAT media like floppies and USB sticks with sync writes, preferring safety over performance (because users often just yank them out)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ext4 used to have a bug when outages zeroed open files - it has long been fixed but the bad taste in my mouth remains to this day. At the same time I BSOD'ed Windows 20 times in a row and nothing happened.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not deep enough into Windows internals to say whether a bsod has the same effect as a power outage - I suspect not. OP is really not asking to travel back in time to the point where ext4 was buggy and make a file system decision there, but here and now.

Comment: BSOD forces the NT kernel to stop writing anything to the disk the moment it happens, including flushing buffers to the disk, so it behaves exactly like an outage (except for a kernel (mini)dump).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both NTFS and ext2/ext4 are damaged by an unclean shutdown.
This is caused by cached metadata, open files, file left open after being deleted, partially written files, and many other issues.

The resilience of the repair process in both has improved dramatically over the last 20 years.  It's just that ext4 is very noisy about its repairs, while NTFS just takes longer to boot while it silently does its repairs.

Some of the ext4 repairs (like finalizing deleted files that were open when the system crashed) cause lots of scary messages during the filesystem check at next boot, but this is completely harmless, and is something that would have eventually happened (but silently) anyway if the system hadn't crashed.

I could say that ext4 damage is more likely than NTFS damage on unclean system shutdown because linux has typically more things running at once and using the filesystem than a windows machine could, but this would just be mean and possibly not even true.

So it only seems like ext4 is more sensitive than NTFS.  In reality, it's just that ext4 tells you what it is doing while NTFS (obviously rightly) assumes that mere users don't need to know what is going on.

Comment: *but this is completely harmless* - not always. *linux has typically more things running at once* - not the case with Windows 10/11 which literally have over 100 applications writing to the disk simultaneously. This is not an answer, this is an opinion.

Comment: Honestly, this is as much of an answer as the question permits. The answer even addresses the potential number-of-writing-processes misconception that you complain about!

Comment: Yes, fixing deleted files after a crash is 100% completely harmless, and is almost always one of the things, and frequently the only thing that fsck fixes.  Other things may be less harmless, but that one is always harmless.  And I'll up your 100 applications to my 443 applications.